# Quarkus app as Azure function with time trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, quarkus

i am trying to develop a quarkus app that will run as a function and will be triggered by a timer.

my function.json looks like this

```
{
  "scriptFile" :  "../${project.build.finalName}.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "yoink.DoingService.sayDoing",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "timerTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "keepAliveTrigger",
    "schedule" : "*/10 * * * * *"
  } ]
}
```

And here is my code

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DoingService {

  @Inject
  BoingService boingService;

  public void sayDoing( ){
    boingService.sayBoing();
    System.out.println("Doiing");
  }
}
```

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class BoingService {

  @FunctionName("keepAlive")
  public void sayBoing(){
    System.out.println("Boooiiiiin");
  }

}
```

If i execute this i get a npe. If i remove  boingService.SayBoing() from sayDoing() its working.

Do i have to choose a different entrypoint or is there anything else i can do to get my context initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a NPE because Quarkus is not loaded properly so the CDI container didn't wired up the dependencies.

Quarkus only supports running Azure fonctions via its HTTP layer, it didn't support running arbitrary method like you setup.

You can have a look at the following guide for Quarkus Azure fonction support: https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions-http

You can propose an extension proposal to support this kind of Azure function via a new extension proposal on the Quarkus github repository: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/new?assignees=&labels=kind%2Fextension-proposal&template=extension_proposal.md&title=